# How do you make a cast in a databinding expression?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-databinding

I have a sealed class which is being sending via StateFlow. How to cast it in order to retrieve an enclosed value?
I cannot find any example of syntax for databinding expressions.

```
dataclass UserInfo(val name: String)

sealed class ResultOf<out T> {
  data class Success<out R>(val content: R): ResultOf<R>()
  data class Failure(val throwable: Throwable): ResultOf<Nothing>()
}

val model = ResultOf.Success.content(UserInfo("John Doe"))

<variable
            name = "viewModel"
            type="com.example.hello.user.ResultOf"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:text="@{ ??? }"
/>
```

> ```
> viewModel.Success.content.name
>
> (UserInfo)viewModel.content.name
>
> (viewModel as UserInfo).content.name
> ```

None of the above works neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **use parenthesis** just as in code and take into account that **the type must be imported** in the data section

```
<data>
    <import type="com.example.MyStringUtils"/>
    <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
</data>
...
<TextView
    android:text="@{((User)viewmodel.user).lastName}"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

The official documentation is here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#import-classes

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there is a way to go about this using casting in a conditional statement in `XML` at the moment.

You could go about this by creating a `BindingAdapter`. Like so:

```kotlin
data class User(val name: String)

sealed class ResultOf<out T: Any> {
    data class Success<out R: Any>(val content: R): ResultOf<R>()
    data class Failure(val throwable: Throwable): ResultOf<Nothing>()
}
```

**The `BindingAdapter`:**

```kotlin
@BindingAdapter("app:userName")
fun TextView.setUserName(result: ResultOf<User>) {
    text = when(result) {
        is ResultOf.Success -> result.content.name
        is ResultOf.Failure -> ""
    }
}
```

**Layout file:**

```xml
<data>
    <import type="com.example.hello.user.ResultOf" />
    <import type="com.example.hello.user.User" />

    <variable
        name="userResult"
        type="ResultOf&lt;User>" />
</data>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:userName="@{userResult}"/>
```

Comment: Casts are mentioned here:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#expression_language
But alas no examples are given